# How do I update a table in SQL from another existing table on SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL which it creates a new table called **NightTopHit** form the existing table called **winNumber**

```
CREATE TABLE NightTopHit
AS (SELECT 
winNumber,
COUNT(winNumber) 
FROM
ganadoresdia
group by
winNumber
having COUNT(winNumber) > 1
ORDER BY count(winNumber) DESC);
```

Since the table **winNumber** is updated daily I would like to update table **NightTopHit** without dropping the table and running the code above every time.

I tried the SQL below but it does not work not sure how to use SET. Does anyone knows how I can update the table?

```
UPDATE TABLE NightTopHit
AS (SELECT 
winNumber as 'Numero Ganador',
COUNT(winNumber) as 'Veces Ganadas'
FROM
ganadoresdia
group by
winNumber
having COUNT(winNumber) > 1
ORDER BY count(winNumber) DESC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since the structure of the table `NightTopHit` is not changing you can first truncate the table as follows

```
TRUNCATE TABLE NightTopHit;
```

and then fill it up with the updated data again using your query as follows

```
INSERT INTO NightTopHit
(SELECT 
winNumber as 'Numero Ganador',
COUNT(winNumber) as 'Veces Ganadas'
FROM
ganadoresdia
group by
winNumber
having COUNT(winNumber) > 1
ORDER BY count(winNumber) DESC);
```

This will insure that the table will contain the updated data always and you don't have to drop it and recreate it every time there is an update.